# Regex to be made which should include international and Cyrillic characters

Tags: javascript, regex, cyrillic

The regex should fulfill the below conditions:

- Minimum of 3 characters (includes alphabets and numbers, not
  including Special Characters

)

- It must have at least 3 compulsory alpha-numeric characters excluding
  special characters
- All alphabets cannot be the same in a standalone word. However, if
  they are a part of the word, we will allow the same. For example -
  AAA is not allowed but Haaadoop is allowed
- Consecutive alphabets less than or equal to 3 are allowed in a word.
  Ex– Haaadoop is allowed but Haaaadoop is not allowed.
- Three or more consecutive Standalone alphabets are not allowed.
  Example - AA is allowed. AAA is not allowed.
- All numbers can be the same. Example – 111 is allowed
- If more than 1 special character (In a word or Standalone) are
  consecutively entered, it is invalid. Example A-B is allowed, A- -B
  or A-&B is not allowed
- Allow special characters #&()_+[]:;',/.\-"*
- Consecutive dashes, apostrophes are not allowed in any part of the
  string
- It should accept these international and cyrilic characters as well
  ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßŸàáâãäåæçАаБбВвГгДдЕеЖжЗзИиЙйКкЛлМмНнОоПпРрСсТтУуФфХхЦцЧчШшЩщЪъЫыЬьЭэЮюЯяèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ
- These international and cyrilic characters should be accepted in
  starting of the word or in between of the words or in the end of the
  word

Comment: You are trying to do *way* too much in a single regular expression. Break your rules down and apply them one at a time; it will actually be maintainable.

Comment: i tried but was not able to and these all rules needs to be validated in a single field

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not a programming service.

Comment: Sure Qix go on.I have myself made the regex and i dont want any service from you.

Answer (score 0):

^(?!(.)\1+$)(?!.*([a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßŸàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ])\2{3})(?!.*([ '"-])\3)(?![a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßŸàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ]*\W{2})(?=.*[a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-ßŸà-çа-яА-ЯÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßŸàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿè-ÿ])(?!.*[Pp]+(OST|ost)*.*\s*[Oo0]*(FFICE|ffice)*.*\s*[Bb]*.*\s*[Oo0]*.*\s*[Xx].*)[a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-ßŸà-çа-яА-ЯÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßŸàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿè-ÿ0-9\ *"(:,/.\;&)[]_+#'-]{3,40}$

This worked for me